How to prove the sum of concave functions no less than a scalars t is equal to entrywise relationship
here is a theorem about optimization.
Theorem: Suppose $\phi:=(\phi_1,\phi_2,\cdots\phi_m)$ be concave functions defined on a compact set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$.For given scalar $t:=(t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_m)$, there exists an $\mathbf{x}\in\Omega$ such that $\phi(\mathbf{x})\geqslant t$,iff $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\omega_{i}t_{i}\leqslant\max_{\mathbf{x}\in\Omega}\sum_{i=1}^{m}\omega_i\phi_i(\mathbf{x})\quad\text{for all} \ \omega\in\mathcal{W}$$ where $\mathcal{W}:=\left\{\omega\in\mathbb{R}^{m}_{+},\sum_{k=1}^{m}\omega_k=1\right\}$
$`\rightarrow'$ part is obvious,since you already have every conponent in $\phi$ is no less than $t_i$,so you sum them all with some positive coefficient, result still holds.My question lies on the “only if” part.How to prove "if you know the maximum is no less than $t$,then there exits a element s.t. every $\phi_i(\mathbf{x})$ is no less than corresponding $t_i$",thanks!
